# How to get simple elements from term?

Tags: prolog

I want to get simple elements from term and return them in list.

My code:

```
getSimple(T, R) :- 
  compound(T), 
  T =.. [_|R]
```

This query works

```
getSimple(f(1, 2, a), X)
```

Example:

```
X = [1, 2, a]
```

This query returns wrong result:

```
getSimple(f(2, 3, g(a)), X)
```

Example:

```
X = [2, 3, g(a)]
```

Expected:

```
X = [2, 3, a]
```

Comment: *I get wrong answer*. What answer are you looking for? If you need to break down `g(2, 3)` further, then your predicate needs to be recursive.

Comment: Yes, i wanna to take something like [1, 2, a, 2, 3]
But if i try getSimple(T, R):- compound(T), T =.. [_|R], getSimple(R, X).
It`s just return false.

Comment: With your current implementation, if I query, `getSimple(f(1, 2, a, g(2, 3)), R).` I get `R = [1, 2, a, g(2, 3)]`. Please edit your question and include details on what you query, what you get, and what you expect. And make sure you are using the code that you show in your question.

Comment: Edited and ready

Comment: As I mentioned in my first post, you need to solve it recursively. `=../2` doesn't operate recursively. You need to consider each element of the result of `=../2` and check if it is a compound and process it.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comments, the solution needs to be recursive and gets a bit more involved.

Here's a possible solution in which I've left blank spots for you to sort out:

```
% We'll use an auxiliary predicate that handles a list of terms
term_args(Term, Args) :-
    term_list_args([Term], Args).

% This predicate recursively handles a list of terms, each of which is or is not be compound
%    ...so you have to check!
term_list_args([Term|Terms], Args) :-
    (   compound(Term)
    ->  Term =.. [_|TermArgs],                     % If this term is a compound term
        ___,     % Recursively process the term's arguments (TermArgs)
        ___,     % Recursively process the remaining terms (Terms)
        ___      % append the results of the two queries above to obtain Args
    ;                                              % Otherwise, if Term is not compound
        ___,     % Recursively process the remaining terms (Terms) - obtaining TermArgs
        Args = [Term|TermArgs]
    ).
term_list_args([], []).  % base case: An empty list of terms corresponds to an empty arg list
```

Try to fill in the blanks above. Note that "recursively" means you're going to call `term_list_args/2` again on something.